# How do I change the number format of the vertical axis? (when using the EmbeddedChartBuilder in Apps script spreadsheet service)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I have a (container bound) script in one of my Google Sheets. With this script I create a chart based on the data in the sheet. See the picture:

[Sheet and Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yYXI.png)

The apps script (**SCRIPT 1**) that I used, is:

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

function buildChart() {
  //get the sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  //create a new chart
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
    //basics
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COLUMN)
    .addRange(sheet.getRange("D1:H8"))
    .setPosition(10, 10, 0, 0)
    .setOption('isStacked', 'TRUE')
    //title
    .setOption('title', 'Cost Price Development - Stage 3')
    .setOption('titleTextStyle', {fontSize: 12})
    //legend
    .setOption('legend.position', 'none') 
    //vertical axis
    .setOption('vAxes', {0: {title: '€', format: 'short', textStyle: {fontSize: 10}, titleTextStyle: {fontSize : 8}, viewWindow: {min: 79000000}}})  
    //horizontal axis
    .setOption('hAxis.title', 'cost price changes')
    .setOption('hAxis.titleTextStyle', {fontSize : 8})
    .setOption('hAxis.textStyle', {fontSize : 8})
    //chart height
    .setOption('height', 250)
    //colors series
    .setOption('colors', ['tranparant', '#659CEF', 'red', 'green'])
    .build();
  // Insert chart in sheet
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

Currently, (as you can see in the picture above) the numbers on the vertical axis range from 79,000,000 to 81,500,000. However, I want to change the format of these numbers, so that they are shown in millions: i.e. from 79M tot 81,5M.

With the **setOptions()** method I set many options succesfully. But somehow the option **vAxis.format** does not change the format of the vAxis numbers. As you can see in the full script, the following line defines the different vAxis options:

```
.setOption('vAxes', {0: {title: '€', format: 'short', textStyle: {fontSize: 10}, titleTextStyle: {fontSize : 8}, viewWindow: {min: 79000000}}})
```

Only **format: 'short'** does not seem to have an effect.

Subsequently, I changed the above script, so that vertical Axis options are defined in the same way as the the horizontal axis is defined. Below the **SCRIPT 2** version:

```
// create waterfall chart
function waterfallChart() {
  //get the sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //create a new chart
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
    //basics
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COLUMN)
    .addRange(sheet.getRange("g1:k8"))
    .setPosition(10, 10, 0, 0)
    .setOption('isStacked', 'TRUE')
    //title
    .setOption('title', 'Cost Price Development - Stage 3')
    .setOption('titleTextStyle', {fontSize: 12})
    //legend
    .setOption('legend.position', 'none') 
    //vertical axis
    //.setOption('vAxes', {0: {title: '€', format: 'short', textStyle: {fontSize: 10}, titleTextStyle: {fontSize : 8}, viewWindow: {min: 79000000}}})
    .setOption('vAxis.title', '€')
    .setOption('vAxis.format', 'short')
    .setOption('vAxis.textStyle', {fontSize: 10})
    .setOption('vAxis.textStyle', {fontSize: 10})
    .setOption('vAxis.titleTextStyle', {fontSize: 8})
    .setOption('vAxis.viewWindow', {min: 79000000})
    //horizontal axis
    .setOption('hAxis.title', 'cost price changes')
    .setOption('hAxis.titleTextStyle', {fontSize : 8})
    .setOption('hAxis.textStyle', {fontSize : 8})
    //chart height
    .setOption('height', 250)
    //colors series
    .setOption('colors', ['tranparant', '#659CEF', 'red', 'green'])
    .build();
  // Insert chart in sheet
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

However, with **SCRIPT 2** code all defined vertical axis options

```
setOption('vAxis.title', '€')
        .setOption('vAxis.format', 'short')
        .setOption('vAxis.textStyle', {fontSize: 10})
        .setOption('vAxis.textStyle', {fontSize: 10})
        .setOption('vAxis.titleTextStyle', {fontSize: 8})
        .setOption('vAxis.viewWindow', {min: 79000000})
```

have no effect on the chart; see screenshot:

[image: chart 2 with the]

Summarising:

- **SCRIPT 1** results in a chart with most options set and thus visible; only the vertical axis number format definition is not taken over in the chart.
- **SCRIPT 2** results in a chart in which none of the defined options are visible in the chart.

So, my question is: What code must I use so that all defined options of the vertical axis are taken over in the chart?

Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

try setting the option explicitly using `vAxis`, rather than all in one...

```
.setOption('vAxis.format', 'short')
```

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat. I now changed the vAxes options so that they are defined in the explicit way that you suggested. However, somehow now all setOptions are not taken over in the chart.... unfortunately. I will explain below in some more detail what happens.